# Функция подгрузки срабатывает через раз JavaScript

Tags: javascript, изображения

Есть функция которая должная подгружать изображения при скролле. На скролл реагирует хорошо, но вот если оставить окошко на уровне картинок и так перезагрузить, то картинки иногда остаются в загрузке, то есть функция не срабатывает.

вот такие фото -

```
<img src="/img/1.gif" realsrc='/img/img.jpg'>
```

вот такая функция -

```
function isVisible(elem) {

      var coords = elem.getBoundingClientRect();

      var windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
      var topVisible = coords.top > 0 && coords.top < windowHeight;
      var bottomVisible = coords.bottom < windowHeight && coords.bottom > 0;

      return topVisible || bottomVisible;
    }

    function showVisible() {
      var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
      for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {

        var img = imgs[i];

        var realsrc = img.getAttribute('realsrc');
        if (!realsrc) continue;

        if (isVisible(img)) {
          img.src = realsrc;
          img.setAttribute('realsrc', '');
        }
      }

    }

    window.onscroll = showVisible;
    showVisible();
```

Comment: Вот сайт [https://umonreal.ru](https://umonreal.ru), с перезагрузкой кэша иногда не срабатывает

Comment: если оффсет картинки сверху попадает в область скрола документа (от-до размер дока в окне) - тогда загрузить. Я бы такое повесил в скрипт.

Comment: @CodeGust Дело в том что он же же инициализируется - `showVisible()` и такая логика по сути продуманна, но совсем не ясно в чем дело

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/example/javascript/browser-object-model/window-scrollby-method-scroll-the-document-by-100px-vertically.html - попробуйте, как вариант, при загрузки документа прокрутить на 1px вверх или вниз - тогда картинки появятся при перезагрузке дока (я так думаю). 
а вообще, когда показываете код, лучше делать здесь, или, например, на codepen.io, рабочий прототип кода, что бы можно было "поковыряться" в нем другим.